# Name for opposing (complementary) multisets (bags)

Tags: notation, terminology

I am looking for the accepted mathematical name for opposing multisets (or complementary multisets). I have done a Google search and a Stack Exchange search, and have come up empty.

These are the properties of the multiset pair I'm referring to:

- Both are unordered
- Both accept multiple instances of an item (definition of multiset)
- Identical items in each multiset should be equivalent to "cancelling" the elements from both sets (i.e. A = {2, 5, 5}, B = {5, 4} is equivalent to A = {2, 5}, B = {4}).

In addition to the common name, is there a set-notation that can help me define it more formally?

Comment: The last point is unclear. You say that adding an item to one set is equivalent to removing one from the other, but in the example you remove one from both?

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would care to comment on the reasons for the downvote?

Comment: You are correct, I was unsure how to word the comment, which is why I added the example, and mentioned "cancellation". 

I too would like to know why it was downvoted, because this is a very important question for me at the moment. Perhaps my wording is the reason for the downvote? I don't have any clue at this moment. I have changed the question to maybe be more exact.

Answer (score 1):

I FINALLY found an answer to what I was imagining. Called a [hybrid set](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9502214), it can contain negative multiplicity, which would allow the single hybrid set to represent both of the "opposing multisets."

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'd accept this answer if I were you :-) Note the analogy between the definition of integers via equivalence classes of pairs of natural numbers and the connection between hybrid sets and equivalence classes of pairs of multisets.

Comment: I can note that there is a small difference between what I described and the actual definition of a hybrid set. However, I would end up using them isomorphically.

Comment: And please forgive my mathematical language. I'm an amateur at it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [these operations on multisets](http://planetmath.org/operationsonmultisets), you could say that a pair $(A,B)$ of multisets is reduced to the canonical form

$$
(A-(A\cap B),B-(A\cap B))
$$

and all pairs that reduce to the same canonical form are equivalent. Equivalently, you could say that two pairs $(A,B)$ and $(C,D)$ of multisets are equivalent exactly if there are multisets $E$ and $F$ with $E\subseteq A$ and $E\subseteq B$ such that $C=A-E+F$ and $D=B-E+F$.

I'm not aware of any terminology for pairs of multisets under this equivalence.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I believe that with this information and the hybrid set, I can now continue my work.